# Does LiteIDE x14 work at all?

Tags: go, liteide

I'm trying out LiteIDE for golang and there are no docs to speak of and apparently no forum.  I've set the Env for my environment and go installation.  When I try to use it on the hello.go file (as a file or a a project) all I get is

```
<action id="Run" cmd="${TARGETPATH}" args="${TARGETARGS}">
<start=" " workdir="C:/liteide.projects"/>
 

<error msg="process failed to start" />

</action>
```

(Sorry for the formatting but the Code Sample tags in this forum can't handle XML blocks.)

Lots of other people have seen the same thing.

What are the TARGETPATH and TARGETARGS that is shown?

Is there any documentation on how to configure LiteIDE?

Comment: I have used previous versions of LiteIDE just fine (havent tried it since Go1). All I remember having to set up was the GOROOT, GOBIN

Comment: I've got PATH, GOROOT, GOBIN, GOARCH, GOOS, and LITEIDE_GDB set in win64.env to my installation of go1.0.1.windows-amd64.

Comment: On the Windows platform the Zeus editor has support for Go.

Comment: Heh, this just popped to the top of the Go questions because of an edit--this was a problem apparently solved by using v14, LiteIDE is now on v21, and the question doesn't mention version. Does SO have a standard way to deal with q's that only look outdated once you look at the date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LiteIDE apparently does not work.  I filed [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/golangide/issues/detail?id=53) and their advice was to try a recent beta of the next release.  That didn't work either, however.

Answer (score 6):

Just an update for those coming here: I started to use LiteIDE X (x14.1) on Windows 7 and it works superbly. :-) Lightweight and efficient...

Comment: I had very good experience with LiteIDE X 16 and 17 too (on Windows 7) 
And it's the only IDE I got a debugger for go working.   I found all I needed to know on [LiteIDE FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/golangide/wiki/FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but just wanted to add that the latest build x21 is running beautifully. This answers your question "Does it work at all?" with a resounding yes! =D

Also wanted to provide the proper FAQ link as the project has moved to Github. https://github.com/visualfc/liteide/wiki/Faq

Answer (score 0):

I have been using liteide for more than 6 months and it works well.
Current version which I am using is X27.1 & running it on OpenSuSE.

Answer (score 0):

LiteIDE, meanwhile Version X30.3 (December 2016), is quite mature and still actively maintained. I'm using it on Windows 10, Debian Jessie and Ubuntu.

It's a simple, open source, cross-platform Go IDE with unique features other IDE's dont have. The few issues I had were more related to my X11 environment than to LiteIDE itself.

The following operating systems are are currently supported:

- Windows x86 (32-bit or 64-bit)
- Linux x86 (32-bit or 64-bit)
- MacOS X10.6 or higher (64-bit)
- FreeBSD 9.2 or higher (32-bit or 64-bit)
- OpenBSD 5.6 or higher (64-bit)

There are build instruction that let you build LiteIDE on other platforms as well. Just dont expect support for this.